# How to pass an array list from one activity to another without starting it

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist

I have an activity which has an array list

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

i want this array list to be passed to another activity when a Save button is clicked, but i don't want that activity to start...

Usually this code helps in starting an activity

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
 if (v==Save)
            {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArrayList("DONE", activeURL);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Reader2.this, Aggregator.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("reader2", activeURL);
                startActivity(intent);

                }
}
```

but i just want to pass the array and start another activity.
Can you please help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can I ask why you want the second activity to store the data before it gets started rather then use a more standard approach?

Comment: Reference here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242944/passing-arraylist-of-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android/28830434#28830434

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can declare you ArrayList as a static one like this,

```
public static ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

By doing this you can access your ArrayList from anywhere by

```
activity_name.array;
```

where activity_name is the activity or class in which you declare the static ArrayList

Comment: Thanks man you made my concept clear too. This was great help for me too.

Comment: wait, how does this work? It was my understanding that static class members aren't attached to any specific instance of that class. If you were to instantiate two instances of the Activity Class would the static members be shared between the instances?

Comment: @slayton:  Yes, that is exactly how `static` works.  This is a frowned upon practice in general, but I think it works here with the assumption that there will only be one instance of this `Activity`.

Comment: @Lalit Poptani this is not a gud way...as when we use static variable it keeps in memory...And memory cant be release...And make the speed of app slow

Answer (score 2):

you can pass an intent to already running activity.. follow this http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-running-activities for that
in the intent you can add an extra like this

```
Intent contactsIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                ContactCards.class);
        contactsIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetId);
//Bundle containing the serialized list
        Bundle extraContacts = new Bundle();
//Putting the array list templist is the array list here

        extraContacts.putSerializable("CONTACT_KEY", tempList);
        extraContacts.putString("CALL_STRING", CALL_STRING);
        contactsIntent.putExtras(extraContacts);
        contactsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(contactsIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you mention a 'Save' button, I think you would rather save this data to [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) or an [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

I am unsure of what it would mean to 'save' some data to another `Activity` and not start it.

With your data in a persisted state, you should be able to access it from any one of your other `Activity`'s, which is what is sounds like you are after.

Answer (score 1):

use 1st activity

```
    Intent i=new Intent(ArraylistpassActivity.this,second.class);
   i.putStringArrayListExtra("key",arl);startActivity(i);
```

2nd activity:

```
arl=bundle.getStringArrayList("key");
```

Comment: it willnot working for the custom arraylist..**Eg:-** ArrayList<ImagepathModel> arrayList_filepath = new ArrayList<>();