# Passing ArrayList of string arrays from one activity to another in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, android-activity

I want to pass an ArrayList of string arrays from one activity to another in Android.
How can I use `intent` or `bundle`? Please consider that `intent.putStringArrayListExtra` is not working in this case, because it is not for string arrays.

Comment: it should work show us some code. post the stack trace if you have exceptions

Comment: [**Please See this Blog. This Can Help You**](http://startandroiddevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-pass-boolean-int-string-integer.html)

Comment: See this example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242944/passing-arraylist-of-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android/28830434#28830434

Answer (score 18):

Not sure what you mean by  "ArrayList of string arrays"

If you have string array then check the below link

[Passing string array between android activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429036/passing-string-array-between-android-activities)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

ArrayList implements `Serializable`

You can use intents

```
    ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();  
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Second.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", mylist);
    startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve

```
    Intent i = getIntent();  
    ArrayList<String> list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```

`public Intent putStringArrayListExtra (String name, ArrayList<String> value)`

Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Parameters

```
name    The name of the extra data, with package prefix.
value   The ArrayList data value.
```

Returns

```
Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls into a single statement.
```

To pass ArrayList of String array

```
String[] people = {
        "Mike Strong",
        "Jennifer Anniston",
        "Tom Bennet",
        "Leander Paes",
        "Liam Nesson",
        "George Clooney",
        "Barack Obama",
        "Steve Jobs",
        "Larry Page",
        "Sergey Brin",
        "Steve Wozniak"
};
String[] people1 = {
        "raghu", 
        "hello"
};


ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
list.add(people);
list.add(people1);
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key", list);
startActivity(i);
```

To retrieve

```
Intent in = getIntent();
ArrayList<String[]> list =(ArrayList<String[]>) in.getSerializableExtra("key");
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
   String s[]= list.get(i);
   for(int iv=0;iv<s.length;iv++)
   Log.i("..............:",""+s[iv]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with if this is doable or not as things stand with the Bundle class so i would implement a custom object to house your ArrayList. this is a good clean solution for housing other common data that you would need to access in both activities

```
public class MyCustomData implements Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 42432432L;
    public ArrayList<String[]> strings = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public MyCustomData() {

    };
}
```

and then in your Activity:

```
MyCustomData myCustomDataInstance = new MyCustomData();
myCustomDataInstance.strings = //set it here;

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyNextClass.class);
bundle.putSerializable("key", myCustomDataInstance);
selectedIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(selectedIntent);
```

also i would suggest using an arraylist of arraylists instead of an arraylist of arrays

Answer (score 0):

So you want to pass a List of String arrays, not a List of Strings, right? Since `ArrayList` is serializable, you can add it pretty easy:

```
ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
// Add some String[]
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("xxx", list);

// And to get it back
ArrayList<String[]> list = (ArrayList<String[]>) i.getSerializableExtra("xxx");
```

Answer (score -4):

This Problem have a simple solution you can simply declare ArrayList public & static in your First activity and then call it in another one.

**In your First Activity**

```
public static ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList();

myList.add("some_value");
```

**In second Activity**

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),FirstActivity.myList.size().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```