# get only one element from arraylist while send data from notification click

Tags: android, push-notification, android-pendingintent

Hello i dsplayed notification and according to the distance from circle i displayed notification and i want to send all marker emailid to pending intent activity.

Here is my code

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (circle != null)
        circle.remove();
    this.location = location;
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
//        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    circle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .strokeColor(Color.RED)
            .strokeWidth(2)
            .radius(1000));
    circle.setCenter(latLng);


    float[] distance = new float[2];
    if (!abc.isEmpty()) {
        mar_list=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < abc.size(); i++) {
            Location.distanceBetween(abc.get(i).latitude, abc.get(i).longitude, circle.getCenter().latitude, circle.getCenter().longitude, distance);

            if (distance[0] <= circle.getRadius()) {
                mar_list.add(locationlist.get(i).get("usrnm"));
                manager1 = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OfferActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("list",mar_list);
                Log.v("TAG",""+mar_list.toString());
                //Here mar_list contain three items but in offer activity only one item is displayed      
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                mBuilder.setOngoing(false);
                Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Offer")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("You Have Entered in Offer zone.To see offer in your area please proceed"))
                        .setContentText("You Have Entered in Offer zone.To see offer in your area please proceed")
                        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                manager1.notify(1, mBuilder.build());



            } else {
                Log.v("TAG ", "" + distance[0] + " radius: " + circle.getRadius());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "outside, distance from center: " + distance[0] + " radius: " + circle.getRadius(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        Log.v("TAG",""+mar_list.toString());
    } else {
        Log.v("TAG ", "" + distance[0] + " radius: " + circle.getRadius());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "outside, distance from center: " + distance[0] + " radius: " + circle.getRadius(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

According to my code it will pass only first value i want all arraylist to pass to next activity

here is offeractivity

```
public class OfferActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<String> mylist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_offer);
    mylist = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");
    Log.v("TAG", "" + mylist.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: change this  `if (distance[0] <= circle.getRadius()) ` to this `if (distance[i] <= circle.getRadius()) {`

Comment: distance is float      float[] distance = new float[2];

Comment: tell me that arraylist name ? `i want all arraylist to pass to next activity`

Comment: Locationlist contain all the marker location mar_list contain all the marker from circle radious   and abc contain all the latlang

Comment: i want to pass mar_list to next activity

Comment: it seems you have to do like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453297/passing-arraylist-of-string-arrays-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android). And also debug properly,whether you are getting all values in arraylist before moving to next activity.

Comment: Ya i am getting all the values before sending to next activity but in next activbity get only first index value

Answer (score 0):

try this:

compile this gradle `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'`

```
String str = new Gson().toJson(mar_list);

intent.putExtra("list",str);
```

get list from intent

```
YourModelClass model = new Gson().fromJson(str,YourModelClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **MainActivity.java** :

change this :

```
 intent.putExtra("list",mar_list);
```

to

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list", mar_list);
```

**offeractivity.java**

Change this :

```
mylist = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");
```

to

```
mylist = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("list");
```